# How to determine the VM limits thresholds on CPU limit from inside a VM or VPS

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, scripting

I was asked to recently to verify that a purchased VM , was provisioned with the appropriate compute from a hosting company. I suspect they are throttling the machines access to the cpu at 8% or 10%

I am inside a Windows 2012r2 VMware (8 cores, SSD, and 24GB memory) **the *hosted VPS/VM* machine is slow and sluggish**. Using the tools below, I tried to investigate, and found that - the CPU /logicalCpus never exceed 10%, often at 8%. **I want to know if the hosting company is throttling the VM's and not providing what was paid for?**

I investigated with the following, to find that we only see 10% at peak, seems like the processes are starved.

- *used,* Task manager CPU
- *used,* Psexec a
- *used,*  watching RESMON- resource monitor

---

1. How can I view/find how much compute/limits have been put on the VM, by the host?
2. What percentages are recommended for VPS's

Comment: Are you monitoring the server during regular operations, or while running a resource load test?

Comment: @GregL I was monitoring under regular operations. However, I also testing simple things, like 1) installing updates 2) installing Software 3) applying a simple policy 4) launcing/opening and closing apps

Comment: I can't imagine any of those tasks would stress the CPU very much and would likely all be single threaded. I'd suggest running a proper load test to see how it performs.

Comment: @GregL I believe your hunch is correct, they're throttling the CPU, I ran a simple factorial 250 on the calc... did not stress the machine beyond *%, but the hosting company throttled it... the apps were still waiting/straved for the CPU